# Apache DS SHA password attribute adding

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I build Apache DS from source, i mean there are all the apache DS projects like

`apacheds all`
`apache ds core`
`apache ds server config`

in my workspace in eclipse.

I changed `config.ldif` in the `apache ds server config`, by changing

`ads-pwdCheckQuality: 2` to `ads-pwdCheckQuality: 0`

clean and build all the workspace and restart the server

but i still cannot add `userPassword` with SSHA or SHA to an entry.

How can i make my project be affected by my `config.ldif` changes?

Thanks

Comment: Is your LDAP client attempting to add a pre-encoded password?

Comment: @TerryGardner thanks.I am using eclipse plugin apache ds studio to connect to server and do adding deleting dn entries. i am manually adding an entry from scratch and when i add it there is no password, when i try to add `userPassword` attribute i select `SHA` OR `SSHA` and it gives `cannot verify the quality of non-cleartext passwords`

Comment: Correct. Consider sending sending a clear-text password over a secure connection, or use a non-secure connection promoted with StartTLS. This permits the server to verify password quality and history and is the superior option.